# DBFreader python 3.7 issues

Tags: python-3.x, dbf

i want to work with dbf Files on Python 3.7 with dbfread Module, it works with a small dbf

```
from dbfread import DBF
from struct import *

table = DBF('usuarios.dbf', load=True)
for item in table:
    print (item)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('NUMUSER', '    0'), ('NOMUSER', 'Rosy'), ('PASSWORD', ''), ('NIVEL', 'SUPER'), ('VALIDAR', 'P?@qMwá¿|Ew}"Q-JW0Q0:iw^'), ('EMAIL', 'MARLENGURROLA@gmail.com|'), ('MAILTIPO', 1), ('MAILFIRMA', None), ('MAILSMTP', 'Ghf2U*wT3Ik?D#>W0@+9@," ¡.deZ+%¿i?GL0oBrO+éZ=KwXw{E(LXIv#ñOññW+t"AruéñAm\\O>YB$iTNv*\'Ñé2).*qv#88XZ5k%KK%R}~¡oOgiTó\'=#'), ('HUELLA1', None), ('HUELLA2', None), ('METODO', 0), ('ACTIVO', True)])
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

but when i try with a large dbf it shows error

```
from dbfread import DBF
from struct import *

table = DBF('docum.dbf', load=True)
for item in table:
    print (item)
```

Output2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\rdbfs.py", line 4, in <module>
    table = DBF('docum.dbf', load=True)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\dbfread\dbf.py", line 121, in __init__
    self._read_header(infile)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\dbfread\dbf.py", line 206, in _read_header
    self.header = DBFHeader.read(infile)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\dbfread\struct_parser.py", line 41, in read
    return self.unpack(file.read(self.struct.size))
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\dbfread\struct_parser.py", line 36, in unpack
    items = zip(self.names, self.struct.unpack(data))
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 32 bytes
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

i don't know about pack or unpack data in python, can you help me guys? or give guideance. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use `dbfread` myself, so I don't know why it's not working.

You can try using my library, [`dbf`](https://pypi.org/project/dbf/), which would look like:

```
import dbf

table = dbf.Table('usuarios.dbf')
table.open()
for item in table:
    print item

record = table[0]  # first record
print record.numuser
print record.nomuser
```

Comment: I know this is late, but can I use this dbf module with Python3

Comment: @RahalKanishka: Yes, you can.  The above example would be using the function form of `print`, so `print(item)` and `print(record.numuser)`.

Comment: Thanks, I was struggling to set up dbf for python 3. And I finally set it up and tried your code and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

it works!!

```
    import dbf

ruta = 'Y:/SAITBC/'
table = dbf.Table(ruta+'clientes.dbf')
tablita = table.open()
print(tablita)

#for item in tablita:
#   print(item)

record = tablita[0]
print (record['nomcli'])
```

output:

```
    Table:         Y:/SAITBC/clientes.dbf
    Type:          Foxpro
    Codepage:      cp1252 (Windows ANSI)
    Status:        DbfStatus.READ_ONLY
    Last updated:  2018-12-20
    Record count:  1282
    Field count:   79
    Record length: 1230 
    --Fields--
      0) numcli C(5)
      1) nomcli C(200)
      2) calle C(60)
      3) numext C(10)
      4) colonia C(60)
      5) ciudad C(30)
      6) estado C(20)
      7) cp C(10)
      8) telefono C(30)
      9) fax C(20)
     10) clasif C(5)
     11) ventano N(12,2)
     12) ultvent D
     13) atvent C(40)
     14) atcobr C(40)
     15) rfc C(13)
     16) limcred N(12,2)
     17) saldo N(12,2)
     18) pjedesc N(5,2)
     19) diascred N(3,0)
     20) precioutil C(1)
     21) recepfac C(30)
     22) pagofac C(30)
     23) obs M
     24) email1 C(40)
     25) email2 C(40)
     26) numcta C(20)
     27) uid N(10,0)
     28) numvend C(5)
     29) obligareq L
     30) suspendido L
     31) bloqueasop L
     32) direnvio M
     33) otrosdatos M
     34) impuesto1 N(6,2)
     35) retencion1 N(10,4)
     36) retencion2 N(6,2)
     37) permitecod L
     38) llavecred L
     39) tiposop C(10)
     40) clavecli C(20)
     41) curp C(20)
     42) pais C(15)
     43) nomcomer C(40)
     44) cfgdatdoc M
     45) datosfe M
     46) statusweb N(1,0)
     47) claveweb C(32)
     48) numzona C(5)
     49) metodopago M
     50) metodousar C(2)
     51) tiposys C(10)
     52) licencia N(10,0)
     53) ncontra C(10)
     54) pass C(10)
     55) rsocial N(10,0)
     56) usanom L
     57) contnomi C(10)
     58) passnom C(10)
     59) numint C(10)
     60) cosac C(2)
     61) modi L
     62) altasg D
     63) usocfdi C(3)
     64) formapago C(2)
     65) fechanac D
     66) pjepuntos N(5,2)
     67) pjedescmes N(5,2)
     68) pjedescdia N(5,2)
     69) implocal M
     70) poliza C(10)
     71) vencsait D
     72) usaenl L
     73) vencnom D
     74) rsocnom N(10,2)
     75) usabov L
     76) vencbov D
     77) tiponom C(20)
     78) condpago C(30)
```

PEÑUELAS TAPIA JAIME ROJO
[Finished in 0.4s]

Comment: Because this isn't a actual answer, please delete it once we have this figured out.

Comment: thnx i'll delete it, i just wanted to show you my error, i didn't know how.. srry

Comment: No worries.  New users can't do much so it was a good way to show the problems you were having.

Comment: Thank you so much!